# Функция ntohs - из сетевого порядка байтов TCP / IP в порядок байтов хоста

Tags: c++, c, winsock, winsock2

В описании функции ntohs на MSDN сказано:

> Функция ntohs преобразует u_short из сетевого порядка байтов TCP / IP
> в порядок байтов хоста (который на процессорах Intel является прямым
> порядком байтов).

и

> Функция ntohs возвращает значение в порядке байтов хоста. **Если**
> параметр netshort уже находится в порядке байтов хоста, э**та функция
> изменит его**. Приложение должно определить, нужно ли поменять порядок
> байтов на обратный.
>
> Требуется: Библиотека Ws2_32.lib

Правильно ли будет сказать, что использовать данную функцию нет никакого особого смысла, легче просто написать свою, которая не будет требовать подключения дополнительных библиотек и заголовочных файлов. ?

Comment: Нет, неправильно.

Comment: @ KoVadim, а почему ? :)

Comment: Потому что, скорее всего, Вы напишите ее неверно.

Comment: @KoVadim , а есть основания для этого ? Там же нужно всего лишь два байта местами переставить ? Что именно вы предполагаете под неверным описанием ? Вы бы какую ошибку допустили ?

Comment: А почему это я допустил ошибку? Напишите Вашу реализацию, посмотрим

Comment: @KoVadim, но мой вопрос был не в конкретной реализации, а в самом принципе. Если реализация верная, то смысла использовать именно ntohs нету ?

Comment: если есть готовая функция, то почему бы ее не использовать? другие программисты не будут спрашивать "а что эта функция делает", они не будут смотреть в документацию/код. При переносе на другую платформу, может вдруг оказаться, что там байты не по 8 бит... или порядок уже прямой. Или на целевой платформе уже есть подходящая функция - bswap/XCHG

Comment: @KoVadim, а какое значение имеет порядок байт на другой платформе ? И какое значение имеет кол-во бит в байте ? ntohs не работает с битами же, работает с байтами, сколько бит в них не было бы.

Comment: ну вот собственно Вы и ответили на свои вопросы.

Comment: @KoVadim, не увидел, я только задал вопросы на ваши комментарии. Так и не понял, зачем вы упомянули прямой порядок на другой платформе ?

Comment: допустим, Вы написали программу, она стала успешной и Вы решили скомпилировать ее под новую модною систему, а там порядок прямой (или ещё хуже - смешанный) и все, код компилируется, но работает как то совсем странно.

Comment: @KoVadim, предположим я использую ntohs - разве это что то изменит? К примеру в реализации на WIndows, там так прямо и написали - "Если параметр netshort уже находится в порядке байтов хоста, эта функция изменит его. Приложение должно определить, нужно ли поменять порядок байтов на обратный.". То есть она изменит порядок байт внутри переменной в любом случае не зависимо от того, какой порядок сейчас находится на платформе на которой вызвана эта функция. Или я не прав ?

Comment: я ответил на этот вопрос в самом начале. Если платформа имеет прямой порядок байт, то обычно эти функции внутри просто делают return или прячут по пустым макросом. Поэтому, эта функция для платформ с обратным порядоком поменяет, для платформ с прямым - ничего не сделает. Но программист сам должен понимать, что вот тут у него данные, которые хранят сетевой порядок, а вот тут, которые хостовый, и при этом не имеет значения, как именно там байты расположены. "должно определить, нужно ли поменять порядок байтов на обратный" имеется ввиду сетевой-хостовый

Comment: @KoVadim, в документации к функции черным по белому написано: "Функция ntohs возвращает значение в порядке байтов хоста. Если параметр netshort уже находится в порядке байтов хоста, эта функция изменит его." Откуда вообще это взялось - "Если платформа имеет прямой порядок байт, то обычно эти функции внутри просто делают return". Вы просто берете и игнорируете информацию и пишите ответ, как будто бы это информации нет. Разве это правильно ?

Comment: возможно потому, что msdn  в основном написана для x86 платформы? и Майкрософт знает, что ее программисты не умеют смотреть исходный код оси (в виду его недоступности)?

Comment: @KoVadim, возможно, но вопрос то я задал именно с учетом этого нюанса. Даже выделил его жирным.

Comment: Читайте оригинал, там лучше написано "then this function will reverse it" - написано, что она сделает обратную операцию - то есть, с сетевого назад в хостовый. И это так и есть.

Comment: @KoVadim, там же и написано, что "If the netshort parameter is already in host byte order" - "then this function will REVERSE it". Там ничего не сказано, про то, что "с сетевого назад в хостовый".

Comment: документацию надо уметь читать. я уже устал объяснять одно и тоже. Если понимать, как это все устроено, то документация становится очевидно. Наоборот - не всегда.

Comment: Из всех ваших теологических споров я так и не понял, что есть прямой и обратный порядок, а точнее что есть BE, а что LE?

Comment: @0andriy, мы вроде не спорили именно про BE и LE, я лишь спросил зачем использовать именно библиотечную ntohs, если она все равно меняет порядок байт -  в независимости от BE и LE.

Comment: Так а я этого и не утверждаю, мне непонятна русскоязычная терминология.